# matching key against different pairs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Due to different names of an attribute I need to match a key of a key value pare against a regex.

The possible names are defined in a dict:

```
MyAttr  = [
    ('ref_nr', 'Reference|Referenz|Referenz-Nr|Referenznummer'),
    ('color', 'Color|color|tinta|farbe|Farbe'),
]
```

The import attributes from an item in another dict:

```
ImportAttr  = [
    ('Referenz', 'Ref-Val'),
    ('color', 'red'),
]
```

Now I would like to return the value of the import attributes, if it is a known attribute (defined in my first dict MyAttr) matching different spelling of the attribute in question.

```
for key, value in ImportAttr:
    if key == "Referenz-Nr" : ref      = value
    if key == "Farbe"       : color    = value
```

The goal is to return the value of a possible attribute if it is a known one.

```
print(ref)
print(color)
```

Should return the value if "Referenz-Nr" and "Farbe" are known attributes.

Obviously this pseudo code does not work, I just can't get my head around a function implementing regex for a key search.

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear for me but maybe you want it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

MyAttr  = [
    ('ref_nr', 'Reference|Referenz|Referenz-Nr|Referenznummer'),
    ('color', 'Color|color|tinta|farbe|Farbe')
]

ImportAttr  = [
    ('Referenz', 'Ref-Val'),
    ('color', 'red'),
]

ref, color = None, None

for key, value in ImportAttr:
    if key in MyAttr[0][1].split('|'): 
        ref = value
    if key in MyAttr[1][1].split('|'): 
        color = value

print("ref: ", ref)
print("color: ", color)
```

The split can split the string into a list of string by the separator ("|" character here) then you can check is the key in that list or not.

The following solution is a little bit tricky. If you don't want to hardcode the positions into your source you can use locals().

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

MyAttr  = [
    ('ref', 'Reference|Referenz|Referenz-Nr|Referenznummer'),
    ('color', 'Color|color|tinta|farbe|Farbe')
]

ImportAttr  = [
    ('Referenz', 'Ref-Val'),
    ('color', 'red'),
]

ref, color = None, None

for var, names in MyAttr:
    for key, value in ImportAttr:
        if key in names.split('|'):
            locals()[var] = value
            break

print("ref: ", ref)
print("color: ", color)
```

Comment: What are the "a" and "b" in the LOOKUPS? If you want to finde the keys whith them then better to use a dict instead of a list of tuples.

Comment: @MiklosHorvath "a" and "b" are not needed, was a try to solve it. The only thing that matters is the different sorts for Reference and Color. My goal is to match those and other variants in order to match "Reference" inside key and "color" inside key

Comment: @MiklosHorvath I edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: Ok, I see you have changed the positions in the myAttr (LOOKUPS). I need to edit my post because the readers downvoted it after your edit. They thought my answer is bad but not just your queston changed :D

Comment: Done. I have edited my answer, try the examples please :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can also use `pandas` to solve this problem for the large data sets in this way.

> get_references_and_colors.py

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import json

def get_references_and_colors(lookups, attrs):
    responses = []

    refs = pd.Series(re.split(r"\|", lookups[0][0]))
    colors = pd.Series(re.split(r"\|", lookups[1][0]))
    d = {"ref": refs, "color": colors}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d).fillna('') # To drop NaN entries, in case if refs 
                                    # & colors are not of same length 

    #               ref  color
    # 0       Reference  Color
    # 1        Referenz  color
    # 2     Referenz-Nr  tinta
    # 3  Referenznummer  farbe
    # 4                  Farbe

    for key, value in attrs:
        response = {}
        response["for_attr"] = key

        df2 = df.loc[df["ref"] == key]; # find in 'ref' column

        if not df2.empty:
            response["ref"] = value
        else:
            df3 = df.loc[df["color"] == key]; # find in 'color' column
            if not df3.empty:
                response["color"] = value
            else:
                response["color"] = None # Not Available
                response["ref"] = None

        responses.append(response)

    return responses


if __name__ == "__main__":

    LOOKUPS  = [
         ('Reference|Referenz|Referenz-Nr|Referenznummer', 'a'),
         ('Color|color|tinta|farbe|Farbe', 'b'),
    ]

    ATTR  = [
        ('Referenz', 'Ref-Val'),
        ('color', 'red'),
        ('color2', 'orange'), # improper
        ('tinta', 'Tinta-col')
    ]

    responses = get_references_and_colors(LOOKUPS, ATTR) # dictionary
    pretty_response = json.dumps(responses, indent=4) # for pretty printing
    print(pretty_response)
```

> Output

```
[
    {
        "for_attr": "Referenz",
        "ref": "Ref-Val"
    },
    {
        "for_attr": "color",
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "for_attr": "color2",
        "color": null,
        "ref": null
    },
    {
        "for_attr": "tinta",
        "color": "Tinta-col"
    }
]
```